# python, creating a random sentence generator from dictionary

Tags: python

```
def sentence_generator(filename, length=10):

    random.seed(1)  # Set the seed for the random generator - do not remove

    my_tuple1 = learn(filename)
    sorted_word_list = sorted(my_tuple1[1])

    i = 0
    while True:
        word = random.choice(sorted_word_list)
        word1 = ""
        for i in range(length):
            word1 = word1 + " " + str(word)
            next_word = my_tuple1[1].get(word)  # Returns None if not found
            if not next_word:
                next_word = my_tuple1[0]  # Fallback to '' if not found
            word = random.choice(next_word)
            i = i + 1
        yield word1
```

so this is the code that I have so far, and I am attempting to create a random sentence generator that takes the key of a dictionary(which is a word) and then the next word will be a value of that key. The cycle then keeps repeating. Learn returns a tuple(word, dictionary). That word will be used if the key has no values. Also, the parameter(defaults to 10) indicates how long the sentence should be hence the for loop. I just need a little help getting into the right direction of creating a generator, cause I am a bit lost rn.

Comment: this seems basically right, although I would ditch the `length` arg and and the `for i in range(length)` loop, just run that code in the while loop. Then you can call `next()` on the generator for each new word you want.

Comment: @RobinDavis oh wait, i forgot to mention that it needs to be a certain length, and the parameter(which is length=10) indicates how many words the sentence should be. That's why I have the for loop there.